# How to update MongoDB data with JQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, mongodb, body-parser

I have been trying to update mongoDB data (User data) with a PUT request from Ajax but can't get it to update. I'm not exactly sure how to input the data to mongoDB, I have been looking at many stackoverflow questions but I couldn't find my answer. Also, I'm kind of new to Ajax so any help is much appreciated! Thank you.

---

**Edit.ejs**

```
    <% include ../partials/header %>

<h1>Edit your profile</h1>


<p id="updateData"></p>

<form method="POST"> 
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="<%= user.name %>">
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="<%= user.email %>">
    <a id="saveButton" href='javascript:void(0)' data-userid="<%= user._id %>">Edit</a>
</form>

<script>
    //Get/read

    $(function() {
        $("#saveButton").on('click', function () {
            var id = $(this).data("userid");
            var data = {
                name: $("#name").val(),
                email: $("#email").val()
            }
            $.ajax({
                method: "PUT",
                url: '/profile/' + id + "?_method=PUT",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: data
            }).success(function(data){
                updateData.append("<p>Response: Data saved!</p>");
                console.log("Successful!" + data);
            }).fail(function(data){
                console.log("Oops not working" + data);
            });
        });
    })
</script>


<% include ../partials/footer %>
```

**Server Side (node.js)**

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });
var User = require("../models/user"),
    { userIsLogged } = require('../config/auth'), // check if user is logged in
    { checkIfBlogOwner } = require('../config/auth'); // check if user is logged in


// UPDATE the Profile
router.put("/:id", userIsLogged, function (req, res) {

    var name = req.body.name;
    var email = req.body.email;

    User.findOneAndUpdate(req.params.id, { $set: { "name": name, "email": email } }, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            res.send("Error" + err);
        } else {
            // res.redirect("/profile/" + req.params.id);
            res.send("From router Put: Worked!");
        }
    });
});



//Global Router
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: What is the error it returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findOneAndUpdate` expects as first argument an object that specifies the search criteria. So you would have to change your query from this:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(req.params.id, ...)
```

to this

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, ...)
```

Comment: :facepalm: Thank you so much!